# Can I develop a game for Kinect without a Kinect?

Tags: unity, debugging, kinect

I have to make a game in Unity3D using Kinect. The problem is I don't have the Kinect yet. I need to wait until they deliver it to me.

Can I imitate Kinect's movement for debugging my app?

Comment: I'd just wait, you probably won't go very far into development until you get your kinect anyway ;)

Comment: maybe, if you have kinect input data to use, also i'm very confident that if you do this and then get an actual kinect later you will run into trouble.

Comment: I recommend to wait, and while waiting, read the docs and code examples explaining the usage of this technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Unity plugins for the Kinect v2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/downloads-docs.aspx) (midway down the page - "Unity Pro Packages") work just fine when a Kinect is absent. You won't get any input from them obviously, but they also don't crash your game or spam the console with errors (which is more than I can say for some other plugins... ;) )

So you should be able to install the SDK and Unity plugins and start writing your code that interfaces with the Kinect while you wait for the device to arrive.

Testing the code in the meantime will be tricky. The plugins don't contain an emulation feature so far as I'm aware, so you'd have to insert your own.

For example, when making [Glimpse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sn9JEMfEZg), we made it so that the gamepad buttons could emulate the eyes closing, letting both developers test the game even though we had only one Kinect device between us.

([Some older plugins](http://ucsim.uc.edu/blog/2014/02/how-to-use-microsoft-kinect-with-unity/) I've used in the past have an emulation built-in, but I've never used that feature so I can't say whether it's worth the grief of dealing with an out-of-date and non-official implementation. I'd lean toward sticking with the Kinect SDK v2.0 because it's so much nicer to use)

How complex your emulation code would have to be depends on what you're trying to emulate. It would be easy to add a bit of debug code to the ColorSourceManager so it always returns a particular texture, or the output of a webcam. Emulating skeletal movement would be trickier.

If you're interested in pursuing emulation and need some help, I'd recommend creating a new question, describing the exact use case you're trying to emulate and how. (eg. I'm trying to emulate a skeleton standing 1.5m away from the kinect, which moves its right hand in the direction I move my mouse)

Comment: Thank you for your advices :) For now I will make an app logic and just simulate some simple kinect cases with mouse.

Answer (score 5):

Can you? Yes. 
Should you? No.

You won't be able to accurately test without the correct hardware. If you have it coming, you should just wait so you don't make yourself do extra work.